# How can flask render a page before some task(like email sending) has not finished

Tags: python, flask, registration, email-validation

How can flask render a page before some task(like email sending) has not finished?

## Issue

In our case, while user submit register info to server, server will send out a certification email first and then render a success page. But it always take 3~5 seconds to finish the email sending, which mean it take at least 3s to get response after he submit the register information.

## What we have done

### 1. Signal

We have try send a signal and trigger a mail-sending function to do this thing:

```
if approved:
    # ...

    send_activation_signal.send(email)

    login_user(u)
    return redirect(url_for('register_success'))
```

#### result

every thing is OK except it still take at least 3s before the register_success page is rendered.

### 2. Fork a thread

fork a thread to finish the email sending

```
t = threading.Thread(target = send_activation, args = (email, username, email_confirm_code, ))
t.start()
```

#### result

but it looks like request context is not processed in correct way.

```
> Exception in thread Thread-2: Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py",
> line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
>     self.run()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py",
> line 505, in run
>     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)   File "/Users/arthasshih/flask/happyvs/main_app/views/user.py", line 267, in
> send_activation
>     app.logger.debug("sending #############")   File "/Users/arthasshih/virtual_evns/normal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/local.py",
> line 336, in __getattr__
>     return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)   File "/Users/arthasshih/virtual_evns/normal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.3-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/local.py",
> line 295, in _get_current_object
>     return self.__local()   File "/Users/arthasshih/virtual_evns/normal/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.8-py2.7.egg/flask/globals.py",
> line 19, in _lookup_object
>     raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context') RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

Comment: Sending an email is nothing you need to put in a separate thread or a task engine. If it takes that long something is wrong with your mailserver's configuration.

Comment: @ThiefMaster you are right, it is the issue of the connection between my server to the mail server.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced this issue when setting up email sending in flask but the issue is not flask. This process has to be run  asynchronously if you want flask to return before finishing send mail task but it is running synchronously here so thats why the wait.

The solution is using [Celery: Distributed Task Queue](http://celeryproject.org/).This text is from their home page:

> It  is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing.Tasks can execute asynchronously (in the background) or synchronously (wait until ready).

There is also a Flask extension called [Flask-Celery](https://github.com/ask/flask-celery/) which makes it easy to integrate celery with flask.

Simple add mail sending task to celery's asynchronous task queue and render page. You have to make sure that celery generates some error log if the task fails otherwise you would not if mail is sent or not.

Comment: fyi, flask-celery is deprecated. don't use it! you can easily use celery directly without that extension: "SINCE CELERY 3.0 THIS IS NO LONGER NEEDED"